# Gradle Build Problem: Execution failed for task ':app: mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have just installed Android studio and when I try to run an empty activity it shows a Gradle Build problem.

[image]

Comment: Don't add errors as screenshots; copy-paste them into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an ic_laucher_round.xml file in your project has some error so go to your file and check for error and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you've chose *Android 7 or higher* support, but didn't create the XML file for proper icon creation. Here's the path of missing file:

```
C:\Users\felip\Desktop\Felipe\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml
```

The easiest way to fix the error is to create this file and to copy *ic_launcher.xml* content into it. Unless you want the icon on *Android 7+* to look different though.

It's obvious, because *Android Studio* told you so. Please, pay more attention to the output text, especially the red one. It mostly explains what happened and what caused the exception.

Comment: Hello Silvian, i read the error but i didn't understood bescause i am just starting with Android Studio. I have the file you are talking about (C:\Users\felip\Desktop\Felipe\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml) i should copy ic_launcher.xml anyway?

Comment: @FelipeTillard As I said, copying the content is the easiest way, but not the only one. Make sure your ic_launcher_round.xml have proper structure and links on existing objects. Its content can be very similiar to ic_launcher.xml, so you can use tha last one as an example and see what is wrong with your file. And yes, if you already have the file, there's no way it can be blank.